# INSERTINTO Query in python as a String and Display?

Tags: python, list, insert-into

first reading Json file:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:    
data = json.load(data_file)

pprint(data)
```

after reading json file,i want to fetch only some parameters from json not all.

like: temperature 1,temperature 2,timestamp

after that;
i want to implement some INSERT INTO query as a String in one LIST or Object
and print that LIST.

In that insert Query, i want to insert some five records and display that records.

Please help me out with this script.

Comment: Do you want to append values in a list or insert them into a database?

Comment: Here, `data` is a dictionary. As, we don't know how this dictionary look like, we can't help you on that.

Comment: use this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/272/json-module#t=201611130550527723123 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=python&query=sql

Comment: yes @serjik i want to insert them into database.but as a trial first i want to implement insert into query and store it in a list or something else(you suggest) and display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the json content to the data variable, you can access it using the name of the attribute you would like to access as index

```
list_values=[]
list_values.append(data['temperature 1']) #add all the values to the list 
print(list_values)
```

You can treat the json values, the same way you treat the dictionary.

Comment: and how can we add INSERT INTO qurey as a string ??

Comment: how we can insert new data ?

Comment: use append operation in list

Comment: yes.if i am giving like this;
list_values.append(data['temperature 1':'53.2'])
its showing error.

Comment: you are trying to add key value pair to a list which is not possible, you can add key value pair in a map. Look for python map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128057/discussion-between-arunagiriswaran-ezhilan-and-tb-m).